# What version of recyclerview should I use in dependecies?

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, build.gradle, android-recyclerview

I want to include recyclerview  in my application , I've updated  the whole sdk . The android support repository is version 17 ,android support library is version 23 . I've recyclerview folder in sdk\extras\android\support\v7 directory .

For adding the library , I've put these in dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0.+'
}
```

when I rebuild the project ,it shows me this error :

> ```
>    Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0.+
> <a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
> ```

What version of recyclerview should I use in dependencies ? How to know it?

**EDIT**
I solve the last problem with the help of a friend , this is the new gradle :

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

Now I get this error :

```
 F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml
Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'...............
```

How to solve this one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this issue becuase

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0.+'
```

**is wrong.**

You can use

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

But you can't use

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0.+'
```

Of course I **suggest you using the last support library**, currently the 23.1.0

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
```

Pay attention. This requires to compile with *API 23*.

Also I suggest you **avoiding the +**. It is not a good choice because in this way you can't replicate your build in the future.

Comment: thanks , it solves the problem , but i'm still confuse . How should I now what version should I use ? I did go to module settings ->dependencies and add  the recycle view , the android studio add it to my project .

Comment: sorry , I rebuild the project, I got this error now : F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml

Comment: @navidjons Open a new question with the full stacktrace.If you are using the v23 you have to compile with api23 your project.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti
I get Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0 (included in my gradle file dependencies also...)
Whats this one for?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I was using support libraries version 23.0.1 easily but cannot update to 23.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Better to use the latest dependency supported by android to get the latest feature and fixes provided by Android. To add a dependency follow the steps mentioned below :

- Right click on your app module in project explorer.
- Select "Module Settings" from the option menu.
- Click on the "Dependency" tab.
- Click the "+" or "-" button to add or remove dependency.
- Click on + and search for dependency by giving it's name and click on the appropriate dependency.

This way you will get the latest dependecy supported by android.

Comment: It is not correct. You dont' need to use the last dependencies. You can use all versions you need, also 22.2.1, 21.0.3. The issue is different. Check below.

Answer (score 0):

use 23.0.0

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```

Comment: You can use v7:23.0.0 or v7:23.0.+ not v7:23.0.0,+

Comment: The syntax with 4 element , with the last + is the real issue on this topic. The version (21 instead of 23) used is not the issue.